# How to sperate properties from JSON data with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json output

```
{
   "categories":[
      "Physical support- 18-64 (RA)"
   ],
   "series":[
      {
         "name":"Buckinghamshire",
         "data":[
            9088
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Lincolnshire",
         "data":[
            9961
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can you separate the Categories and Series into sperate variables with the data?

Comment: `var categories = obj.categories`

Comment: [Going forward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), `let { categories, series } = parsedFromJson;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var json = {
   "categories":[
       "Physical support- 18-64 (RA)"
   ],
   "series":[
   {
     "name":"Buckinghamshire",
     "data":[
        9088
     ]
   },
   {
     "name":"Lincolnshire",
     "data":[
        9961
     ]
   }
   ]
};

var myCategories = json.categories;
var mySeries = json.series;
```

Comment: Side note: By placing it within JavaScript code in this manner, the value of `json` [isn't actually JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).